# voice recognition in android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am an android application developer. I was curious as to how does voice recognition could be implemented using android. There is inbuilt support for speech recognition in android, but how can it be used to implement voice recognition...Are there any links which would help me in learning on this topic..

Thanks

Comment: Check the API demos sample: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get speech recognition working. A little more difficult to get it working well. See this answer to get started:

[Speech recognition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042752/android-speech-recognition/3047498#3047498)

You also might be interested in these links:

http://www.4feets.com/2009/04/speech-recognition-in-android-sdk-15/

[Making a Text-To-Speech Wrapper in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587203/making-a-text-to-speech-wrapper-in-android/3047570#3047570)

[Android speech - how can you read text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160876/android-speech-how-can-you-read-text-in-android/1767929#1767929)